# How to host music bot in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, discord

i have music bot in discord.js, i host it and it works and everything else

BUT.

The bot connect in channel-voice and disconnect immediately, i need a help, i have instaled buildpack ffmpeg [img buildpack installed in heroku.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsNoZ.png)

Has anyone had the same problem and knows how to solve it?
My code is correct, because it is the same as another friend's and his works, but it is the time that he hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku isn't meant to host music bots, let alone any bots. It may work with just something simple, but if you want to host a music bot or a bot equally as intensive, you are going to want to shill out a few dollars on something like OVH or DigitalOcean, that will work much better for you.